# How do I recover a .ogv on ext4?

Tags: ext4, data-recovery

I have very a simple question. How to recover a `.ogv` file on my `/home` ext4 partition?

I overwrote the `.ogv` file (I confused input and output in *Arista transcoder*).

I did research.

- `TestDisk` can undelete files on `FAT` and `NTFS`, but not on `EXT4`.
- `PhotoRec` does not support .ogv recovering.
- `Foremost` also does not support .ogv

More info:

The file is located at: `/home/gasper/Video/Webcam/2011-02-02-181200.ogv`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you immediately stopped writing to that partition, the file could be recoverable, I have just tested it, though on a small `.ogv` file (3 MiB).

The trick is to use `PhotoRec` and in the `File Opt` there tick `.ogg`. The *.ogg* and *.ogv* files have very similar layouts, so `PhotoRec` might be able to recover your file (as it did for me).

You of course have to launch the programme from a LiveCD or other partition, otherwise you may overwrite your original file.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for advice. I did't find any .ogv file when trying recovering all types (maybe I missed). I am going to try again only .ogv. BTW, I am still using partition... why is urgent to stop using? I can reover old files (1 month). Isn't FS smartly using older nodes?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "smartly using older nodes". When a file is deleted, the blocks it used are marked as free, and can be then overwritten at any time. Your chances of recovery are then getting slimmer and slimmer with every write to the disk. --- When I recovered my `.ogv` file, it had `.ogg` extension, but otherwise was the same as the original `.ogv` file.

Comment: Thank you! I was (somehow) able recover file. It's only part of it but it works. I might need to search for all pieces of it. Btw, there is no possibility like restore filename and folder location due to file-system limitation right?

Comment: This is not a "limitation", if you want to delete something, it's deleted, as name suggests :) Most desktop solutions uses the notion of "trash": it's of course not deletion, but moving files to a place, where you can "recover" from. But if really deleted a file, then it's hard to do perfectly since deletion - by design - deletes files :) Use trash instead, if you have doubts you need to get back. Surely some low level tools can scan disk for the deleted file, but it's not perfect especially if further writes may overwrite some data blocks and other problems ...

Comment: @LGB thanks for explanation. I rewritten file not deleted it. EXT doesn't have undelete "feature" like NTFS has (I don't know if this was planned) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext3#Recovery PhotoRec has ability to undelete files on FAT or NTFS

Answer (score 1):

PhotoRec does not utilize the file system, as the original website states https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec

That is the reason why it has a problem with fragmented files and that it likely the reason why

> It's only part of it but it works

Depending on the situation file system-based approaches or raw data-approaches (so called Carving) provide better results.
(e.g. The larger the file and the fuller the disk, the higher the chances for fragmentation). As Carving does not utilize the file system, it cannot determine filename and path of the recovered file.

The thing about the inode reuse is that inodes do not contain all the data (except maybe for very small files, in NTFS very small files are stored in the MFT directly). So even if the inode is still there the section of the disk where the data was stored may be reused (even if the inode is not).
extundelte or ext4magic do utilize the file system and may be helpful.